# site show empty space on website (ipad/mobile)

Tags: css, width, zurb-foundation, space

i have a site ([beta.risingsunjeans.com](http://beta.risingsunjeans.com)) which is currently using Foundation, on screen size looks perfect but in a another resolution (ipad/iphone/mobile) the content looks perfect except that i get a huge empty space on the right sice, i'm already using the right tags on the header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is an element inside your `<nav>` tag that's sticking out to the right side of your page. The problem is on this line:

```
nav[role=main-nav] ul li div {
  width: 1200px;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Changing the width to `width: 100%;` should fix it. You can also set `overflow: hidden;` on the body tag to hide any elements outside it.